Is 造れる intransitive form for 造る?
I am uncertain about the conjugation of 造る used here:

正方形のビルに正方形の部屋は‬造れても縦に３つ

It doesn't make sense for me to understand 造れる as potential form, so I think it must be an intransitive version of 造る. This is similar to the difference between 切る and 切れる. However, I cannot find any reference for intransitive use of 造れる in dictionaries. I wonder if my intuition is wrong.

Grammatically, it is potential form of 造る. Here it is working like an adjective, your understanding is not off though.
The subject of 造れる in the sentence is generic one and the object is 正方形の部屋.
Very literally, it translates to

Within a square building, as for square room, if one can make it (=square room) (as many as possible), it would be three vertically in a row.

Translating it more 'intransitive'-ly, it would be like "the maximum number of rooms that is constructible is three" (I'm not sure what it is intended to mean anyway.)

You can see it as a kind of pattern implying at most.

こんなに大きいハンバーガーは、食べれても２つだ (I can eat at most two hamburgers that is this big)
この部屋（に）は、入れても10人だ (This room can contain at most 10 people)


Thank you! To confirm, in your last example sentence, 入れる is the potential form for 入る, right?

@JohnDavies RIght. I mean はいれても.
